# Group_concat is not displaying all values when use where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat, string-aggregation

I am using a complex query with multiple joins and group_concat and here is the query :

```
 select a.packagename as packagename, a.packageid as packageid, 
 sum(a.packageduration) as days, (a.packageprice + a.seater_4) as price,
 b.statename,
 substring_index(GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT (select f.placename )  SEPARATOR ', 
 '),',',4) placename,
 substring_index(GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT (select d.packagetypename )  
 SEPARATOR ', '),',',4) packagetypename
 from tblpackages a
 join tblstates b on b.stateid = a.stateid              
 join tblpackage_packagetypes c on c.packageid = a.packageid
 join tblpackagetype d on d.packagetypeid = c.packagetypeid
 join tblpackageplaces e on e.packageid = a.packageid
 join tblplaces f on f.placeid = e.placeid
                where d.placename = "placename"
                 group by a.packageid
```

My group_concat for packagetypename is displaying 4 values as per query but placename is displaying only 1 value that is given in where clause?

as the query is group  by package id and for any package i have N places....
Query is working fine as per logic but I want to display all packages for my corresponding package id

Comment: Some sample data and output would really go a long way here.

Comment: output info is already shared.... Do you think that more info is required ?

Comment: I still find it difficult to follow your question without data.  I believe that my suggested answer is partly correct; but I can't say much more.

Comment: yes, ur answer is partially correct......
but its not a correct answer

Comment: So any chance of seeing your data, or do you prefer to keep us guessing?

Comment: hi, do u want to see the data of all corresponding tables or just an output data.
if corresponding table then plz suggest me the way to uplaod it

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest moving the criteria in the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause to the corresponding join, and make that join a left join:

```
SELECT ...
FROM tblpackages a
INNER JOIN tblstates b
    ON b.stateid = a.stateid              
INNER JOIN tblpackage_packagetypes c
    ON c.packageid = a.packageid
LEFT JOIN tblpackagetype d
    ON d.packagetypeid = c.packagetypeid AND d.placename = 'placename'
INNER JOIN tblpackageplaces e
    ON e.packageid = a.packageid
INNER JOIN tblplaces f
    ON f.placeid = e.placeid
GROUP BY
    a.packageid
```

Comment: hi,
Your query is working with extra rows.
I have total 6 packages with id 1,....,6
and as per my query the out ids are 1,2,4 with one placename

and as per ur query I got proper placename and proper packagetypename for id's 1,2&4 But i got extra rows for id's 3,5&6 with NULL on placename coulmn

Answer (score 0):

out put for ur query with bit modification as

```
select a.packagename as packagename, a.packageid as packageid, 
a.packageduration as days, (a.packageprice + a.seater_4) as price,
b.statename,
substring_index(GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT (select f.placename )  SEPARATOR ', '),',',4) 
placename,
substring_index(GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT (select d.packagetypename )  SEPARATOR ', 
'),',',4) packagetypename
from tblpackages a
inner join tblstates b on b.stateid = a.stateid              
inner join tblpackage_packagetypes c on c.packageid = a.packageid
inner  join tblpackagetype d on d.packagetypeid = c.packagetypeid
inner join tblpackageplaces e on e.packageid = a.packageid
left join tblplaces f on f.placeid = e.placeid  and d.packagetypename = 'religious'
                 group by a.packageid
```

pname, pid, days, price,  statename,  placename, packagetypename

---

test1, 1,    3,     111, xyz, (katra, shiv khori),  religious
test2, 2,     3,    444, xyz, (Katra), Religious

test3, 3,    3, 445, xyz, NULL, (Family, Couple, Adventure, Friends)

test4,  4, 555, xyz, (Katra, Patnitop, sanasar, nathatop), (religious, family, couple, adventure)

test6 , 666, abc, NULL, (Family, Adventure, Friends)

Package id 3 and 6 is not required